# Intellij scala bad option -make:transitive

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I was trying to build a scala program in IntelliJ and I had a problem. I reinstalled my Scala plugin and when I try to run my program, I get this:

```
scalac Error: bad option -make:transitive
```

I haven't found anything online related to this in IntelliJ. Anyone know what to do? Like how to remove this option, maybe?

Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It turns out that I was using scala 2.11.7 when the project was made for scala 2.10. I just changed the plugin options to use 2.10. Maybe this helps you in some way.

Answer (score 4):

If you have that problem then:

1. shutdown IntelliJ
2. go to the .idea folder in your project
3. open the scala_compiler.xml
4. remove the -make:transitive parameter by removing the entire line
5. save the file
6. restart IntelliJ and test.

Enjoy.